# Are there any existing tools in zend to make new cms

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

I don't know zend but i want to learn it . i just want to ask that will zend make things easier to add like

```
1)Registration Form
2)user Logins
3)Members area
4)Backend user management
```

or i still have to create those things myself

I want to create my own cms but if i have those things ready to some extent then it will save my time . I am using joomla now which is good for static sites but i want to have more controls myself

If there is anything else , i will learn that too

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there aren't ready to use 'tools' for making CMSs using ZF. You would have to make them yourself. However, ZF does have a lot of components that will ease creation, validation of forms (Zend_Form), user login and authentication (Zend_Auth), controlling user access (Zend_Acl). It also supports modular applications, so you can make backend module for management. Off course, there are many more elements. For example, there is Zend_Tool that can help you setup basic forlder structure of your application, create files for controllers, views or models.

If you are interested in making a CMS using ZF, you could have a look at a book [Pro Zend Framework Techniques Build a Full CMS Project](http://www.apress.com/9781430218791). It gives some valuable information on creating your own CMS. You can also have a look at existing CMSs created using ZF, such as e.g. [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> Powerful Content-Management Framework based on open standards, powered by the ZEND Framework and by ExtJS.
>   [pimcore](http://www.pimcore.org/)